# Laravel 5.6 force download didn't work in linux server but works in localhost

Tags: php, linux, laravel, httpresponse

My Laravel Version is 5.6.

The following code works on localhost when I try to download a pdf file from the storage using Restful API.

```
$file = public_path('storage/').$pathtofile;
$name = 'My Pdf.pdf';   
return response()->download($file,$name,['Content-Type'=>'application/pdf']);
```

Then when I try to push on linux live server it downloads but it creates only the Unconfirmed.crdownload file and it keeps loading and nothing happens and the file is only 200kb.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try remove `/` from `public_path('storage/').$pathtofile;`

Comment: if i do that i can't find the files since my file path is in `/var/www/html/myapi/storage/uploads/invoice/INVOICE-20200001.pdf`

then that response returns `/var/www/html/myapi/storageuploads/invoice/INVOICE-20200001.pdf` if i remove the `/`

Comment: I already download the file maybe after an 1 hour the file is downloaded perfectly but my concern is why took so long since my pdf file size is like 200kb.

Comment: Be aware that PHP.ini settings and/or NGINX (or equivalent) settings may be different between your local environment and that of your server. It is not uncommon to find that your server is very conservative on file uploads and downloads!

Comment: I think it makes sense since my local is like using xampp and my linux server is using nginx. So do you think what is the best configuration for nginx for downloading a file ?

Comment: or maybe a cloudflare problem ? since my site use Cloudflare for ssl

Answer (score 0):

> It is just a cloudflare problem since my site use cloudflare for ssl
>   then when I deactivate the cloudflare SSL from my site. It works fine.